# Custom Polygon Shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How can we create the shape below in CSS?

[image: Polygon Shape]

I've searched everywhere but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is same as your picture

```css
body{
  background:black;
}
.outer{
  margin:40px auto;
  width:1200px;
  height:100px;
  background:#37FFF7;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
 border-bottom: 30px solid white;
 border-left: 70px solid transparent;
 border-right: 70px solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  top:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are other possible ways to create this shape. Let us divide them in 2 broad categories:

### CSS Based Approaches:

Below are few pure CSS based methods to create this shape:

**1- Triangular Borders:**

1. Create two overlays with `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.
2. Apply CSS `border` properties to create triangular effect.
3. Place them in both bottom corners of the element with `position: absolute`.

*Working Example:*

```css
.shape {
  background: linear-gradient(skyblue, skyblue) no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom 30px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shape::before,
.shape::after {
  border-left: 30vw solid skyblue;
  border-top: 30px solid skyblue;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.shape::after {
  border-right: 30vw solid skyblue;
  border-top: 30px solid skyblue;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

**2- Skewed Transformations:**

1. Create two overlays with `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.
2. Apply `skewX()` transformation to create the skewed corners.
3. Place them on each corner of the parent with `position: absolute`.

*Working Example:*

```css
.shape {
  background: linear-gradient(skyblue, skyblue) no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom 30px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shape::before,
.shape::after {
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  background: skyblue;
  height: 30px; 
  left: -45px;
  content: '';
  width: 30%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.shape::after {
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  right: -45px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

**3 - Linear-Gradient:**

In this approach we will use CSS `linear-gradient()` function to draw this shape on the element as a background. As we can apply multiple background images on an element so we will divide this shape in small parts and draw them on the element with precisely controlled sizes and positions.

We can divide this shape in 3 parts and draw them each having specific size and position. I've tried to highlight each part in below image:

[image: Polygon shape in 3 parts]

*Working Example:*

```css
.shape {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 25px, skyblue 25px),
                    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 25px, skyblue 25px),
                    linear-gradient(skyblue, skyblue);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30% 100%, 30% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: left bottom, right bottom, left bottom 30px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

**4 - Clip-Path:**

Clipping means removing or hiding some parts of an element.

`clip-path` CSS property can be used to display a certain area of an element rather than displaying complete area. Any area that is outside the clipping region defined by this property will be hidden.

We can use `polygon()` basic shape to define the clipping region:

```
div.shape {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 25% 100%, 28% 80%, 72% 80%, 75% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}
```

*Working Example:*

```css
.shape {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 25% 100%, 28% 80%, 72% 80%, 75% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
  background: green;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

***Note:*** This approach may not work in all browsers. Check for its [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

---

### SVG Based Approaches:

**1 - Polygon Shape:**

In this approach we will use SVG's `polygon` element to create this shape and fill it with the required background color using `fill` property.

`polygon` element required one attribute `points` which contains a list of points that are joined together to draw a closed shpae.

Below is the necessary code:

```
<polygon points="0,0 0,30 25,30 28,22 72,22 75,30 100,30 100,0" />
```

*Working Example:*

```css
.shape {
  fill: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 30" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www/w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon class="shape" points="0,0 0,30 25,30 28,22 72,22 75,30 100,30 100,0" />
</svg>
```

---

**2 - Clip-Path:**

This is the same concept as discussed in above section. However SVG has its own syntax to define a clipping region.

*Working Example:*

```css
.shape {
  fill: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 30" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www/w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <polygon points="0,0 0,30 25,30 28,23 72,23 75,30 100,30 100,0" /> 
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" class="shape" clip-path="url(#shape)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done simply using the `border` property :

```css
    #inner{
      position:relative;
      margin:0 auto;
      width:50%;
      background:lightblue;
      border-top:40px solid transparent;
       border-bottom:40px solid white;
        border-left:60px solid transparent;
       border-right:60px solid transparent;
       
    }
    #parent{
      width:100%;
      height:80px;
      background:lightblue;
      margin-top:100px;
    }
     body{background:#000;}
```

```html
    <div id="parent">
    <div id="inner"></div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-animation.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #trapezium {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 60px solid white;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    margin-top: 4%
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="container" style="background-color: rgb(55,255,247);height: 60px;">
      <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div id="trapezium"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It may help you.

​